# Problem with Fourier package

Tags: fourier, miktex2.9

I want to use the Fourier package for my personal LaTeX class but when MiKTeX wants to install it, it did not succeed... When compiling my minimal document, MiKTeX echoes me an error message (strangely only in the log file):

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file futr8r): Font futr8r at 604 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

How can I solve this problem?

--

My example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\author{Nicolas T}
\date{\today}
\title{CMWE}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fourier}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

This is a test.
\end{document}
```

An other warning message:
[image: The warning message]

Thanks for help!

Comment: @NicolasT Here, with the full version of MikTeX, there is no problem.

Comment: The compiler tries to make bitmap fonts, which means the type 1 fonts databases have not been updated. Running `updmap --admin` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Bernard said, I tried to enter the `updmap --admin` command in CMD in Windows but it did not succeeded.
I looked for the manual and I found the option `--force`. It is this one we have to enter to make that work!

Thanks a lot for your answer!

So, in conclusion, the command to enter to solve this problem is:

```
updmap --admin --force
```

Comment: I have some doubts. `--force` should normally only affect the xelatex font cache. Normally when `updmap --admin` doesn't work in miktex it means that you have user map files hiding the admin files and should use `updmap` without the `--admin` switch to update them.

Comment: I have solve my problem by this way... That is strange I know... I also tried with no `--admin` but anything happened. So I tried with the `--force` option and I succeeded.

Comment: If you ran `upmap` without `-admin` in between then you updated the user map files and corrected the problem (there is no output when you run the command, it is silent unless you use the --verbose switch).

Comment: Sorry but this answer does not work. The answer in the following link does:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/533845/267665