MikTex installation error
Trying to reinstall MikTex (deleted it first) and I selected private installation, and I'm getting this error - anybody know why / how to fix it? Is there a way to fully wipe MikTex off my drive so there's no remnants so that I can have a fresh install? Normal uninstallation doesn't do that for some reason I think

Deleting and reinstalling - didn't work

try to update the package database (in the menu tasks).

Welcome to TeX.SE!

@UlrikeFischer What do you mean? Where is that?

In the main window of MiKTeX Console on the left side click on “Packages”. There click on the button to update the package database (the forth from the left in the row with the plus and minus icons), or (as said) choose the relevant item in the menu “Tasks”.

It gives me an error:
LinkTargetDirectory: C:\Users\2025a\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64
PathOkay: yes
SystemAdmin: yes
RootPrivileges: no
AdminMode: no
Root0: C:\Users\2025a\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
Root1: C:\Users\2025a\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
UserInstall: C:\Users\2025a\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserConfig: C:\Users\2025a\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserData: C:\Users\2025a\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
Invokers: non-existing

The following issues were detected:
1: major issue: So far, you have not checked for MiKTeX updates.
ERROR DETAILS
Program: miktex-console
Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\papersize.cpp:243
Error: internal error

I split it across 2 comments since it was too long for one @JasperHabicht

If you cross-post the same question on multiple sites, you should include links to all other versions of the question in every post, even in the original one. X-posting without explicit links has the risk of wasting both the time of users who might put time and effort into answering a post, which already has an answer elsewhere, as well as the time of users who might have the same problem but can't find the solutions you might have gotten on one of the other sites you x-posted your question

x-post https://stackoverflow.com/q/79008223/2777074

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I'll delete the one which isn't answered first

@Alex Why not take the opportunity to allow future users of both communities to find whatever answer you might get by adding links to each other?

You can always edit your question and put the error there.

As for the error you get, maybe check how you installed MiKTeX and also how it was previously installed: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/530420/47927 .
